# Retrieve integer value from database

Tags: c#, database

I would like to know how to get an `Integer` value from a database and put it into a `TextBox`.

I know how to get a `VARCHAR` value from a database, which looks like this:

```
public static string email;
public static string Email
{
    get { return email; }
    set { email = value; }
}
```

Then, at the database code:

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    Email = dr["email"].ToString();
}
```

But how do I retrieve an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```c#
Convert.ToInt32(dr["age"]);
```

or maybe

```c#
dr.GetInt32(i); // i: The index of the field to find.
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) link may be useful. :)

Comment: Hi @Ronaldo Araújo Alves , how about the public static  part do i need to change anything as well ?? because it give me error message cannot implicitly convert int to String if i type "public static Int age"

Comment: Are you trying to use this to set a `string` variable / property?

Comment: To set a textbox.Text you need to use `.ToString()` in the variable / property that you are using.

Comment: tq very much brother :) i convert to int from database then convert to text again at textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var result = dr.Field<int?>("intCol");
txtField.Text = result;
```

You should not use `static` for your model class.

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i see thanks for the information , i will remove the static as well